# Log4j2/slf4j - Should commons-logging.jar be removed from classpath?

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j

My logging dependencies currently look like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I noticed that `commons-logging.jar` is still in my classpath, for some reason. Should I exclude that or doesn't that cause any issues?

I didn't notice any problems so far, but I'm still wondering if that jar would still cause problems somehow.

Comment: Is there another dependency that relies on `commons-logging`?

Comment: There probably is, hence it ending up in the WAR. I should check the dependency tree. My question is rather: should I exclude it?

Comment: If you exclude it, what happens to the dependency that expects it to be present and tries to use it?

Comment: No idea :(. I'm really stuck in these logging frameworks in Java. What a PITA, argh.

Comment: Well, what happens when you try to use a dependency that isn't there? Do things work perfectly, or do things go wrong?

Comment: I see where you are going, but it's just that I understood from other answers that commons-logging should not be in the classpath. Hence my question. But you are right, it probably does not make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are dependencies that use `commons-logging`. If it's not present, you'll get `NoClassDefFoundErrors` when they attempt to log. If there were a possibility to have those not even *try* to use the dependency, it wouldn't be a problem. However that's not very likely.

However, if they use `commons-logging` but you're using `SLF4J`, then there's a problem. They're logging in the wrong place (from your point of view). This is where logging bridges come to work. They implement the public API of different logging frameworks, but redirect the logging to what you're using.

For `SLF4J` there are [several bridges](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) (both ways), so instead of bringing in `commons-logging`, you bring in `jcl-over-slf4j`. Libraries will think they're using `commons-logging`, when they're actually using `SLF4J` (which then uses an actual logging *implementation* like Logback).

Easy, huh? ;)

Comment: Wow, this finally made sense. Thanks a lot for explaining! I will add the bridge as dependency. So the next step is to get rid of the `commons-logging.jar`. Should I add a Maven exclusion to every project that somehow depend on `commons-logging`, which might be frustrating to maintain int he future, or is there a more clever way to get rid of that dependency? If this makes sense... :)

Comment: By the way, FYI, I decided to move away from LOG4J and decided to replace it by Logback. I like the fact that you can alter the configuration via JMX in Logback.

Comment: I'm not aware of any catch-all solution. This is mainly a problem with older libraries, when `commons-logging` was an ubiquitous dependency. It does make your pom pretty ugly, but they're usually not that pretty to begin with. Good choice with Logback, it's definitely a better framework than Log4J (although I've heard Log4J2 is "the best" these days, don't really care that much). I fixed your tags too, there was `log4j2` instead of `log4j`.

Comment: Kayaman: for your interest, I found a clever way to remove all dependencies to `commons-logging`. It's done by depending on an empty `version 99`, as explained on https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html. It works on my build.

Comment: Ah, that's nice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, exclude the commons-logging dependency and add the log4j-jcl bridge instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

SLF4J API is also redundant because it is already a transitive dependency of the log4j-slf4j-impl binding.

Answer (score 1):

if you using `slf4j` for logging provider, you need add bridge provider to your dependency. below is my working setup for spring boot `v3.2.1` gradle project with [JDBC SQLite](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) which used `slf4j` for logging provider.

configuration

```
configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    configureEach {
        exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
        exclude group: "ch.qos.logback", module: "logback-classic"
        exclude group: "commons-logging", module: "commons-logging"
    }
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.compilerArgs.add("-parameters")
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
}
```

dependencies

```
implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.25"
implementation "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:2.1.0-alpha1"
```

result
[image: result]